# power automate - get number of rows returned from excel table query

Tags: excel, forms, power-automate

I have an excel table which starts off empty.

I have a form that collects data.

there is a name picklist field in the form that has data like "Brian Jones:607"

The form kicks off a powerautomate flow.

The flow picks out the 3 number string after the colon and this becomes a unique id (it is converted to an integer), lets call it Employee_ID

I want the flow to see if the unique id exists in the excel table under the ID column.

I'm using a "list rows present in a table" action, with a filter query in it that is Employee_ID = EMployeeIDFromFrom and a select query of Employee_ID.

so I should either get nothing or 1 row. (or possibly null....but i dont know how to handle that)

then i have a conditional test based on if there is anything output from that query. (this is where the problem is - i dont know how to do this, i have tried variables and arrays so far and they dont work, i dont really know how to put the results into the array and i cant check whats in the array as i have no idea how to get it to show me the contents of it, like i would if i was writing code)

if there is a result, then use the id to update the row, if there isnt, then add a row.

the problem i am getting is i am clearly not getting the information out of the get rows from table properly. all i want to know is if there are 0 or 1 rows returned from it. once i know that i am fine, i have already done the rest.

lastly, i would love to know how i print to screen or otherwise the outputs of the statements - i'm finding it very hard to troubleshoot the issues because i cant see what is coming out of the get rows from table.

If my approach is wrong please tell me how to do this in another manner.

thanks in advance for your help.